# change row values with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a column where I want to apply a function to each item (row) in that column. When the function is applied, the function returns a `result`. I want to replace the original value of that cell with the value returned from the function. How can I do so?

```
result = [f(x) for x in df['col']]
```

Opting for list comprehensions because it's faster than iterations/apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign back output to column:

```
df['col'] = [f(x) for x in df['col']]
```

What working same like [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(f)
```

---

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map(f)
```

Comment: Is apply or map more efficient than list comprehensions?

Comment: @a125 - It depends of data and function, but I guess yes. the best test in real data

Comment: @a125 - Is possible also see data and function?

Comment: The function iterates through a dictionary, finds cosine similarity between a few items and then returns the max value from another dictionary.

Comment: @a125 - If use dictionaries then `list comprehension` or `map`should be faster like `apply`, the best test.

Comment: Is it possible to include a condition in the list comprehension? For instance, only apply the function if that particular cell is not NaN. I tried this but it doesn't work. ```df['col''] = [f(x) for x in df['col'] if (df['col'] != "NaN")]```

Comment: Use `df['col''] = [f(x) if pd.notna(x) else np.nan for x in df['col']]`

Comment: Is it also possible to add a check for an additional column? For eg, to apply a function only if the saw row value from ```df['second'] == "YES"```

Comment: @a125 - then use `mask = df['second'] == "YES"` and `df.loc[mask, 'col''] = [f(x) for x in df.loc[mask, 'col']`